# Synergy triple monitor server one monitor client

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, synergy

ok so i have a laptop as my client and a dekstop as my server my desktop has three monitors and I want the client to be situated above the leftmost monitor of my server as such

```
 ________________
|                |
| client 1       |
|                |
|----------------|
 ________________ ________________  ________________
|                ||               ||                |
| server left    || server center || server right   |
|                ||               ||                |
|----------------||---------------||----------------|
```

I'll assume for now that I'll have to write a config file for this, if anyone can help me it'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Synergy considers all of the monitors connected to a computer to be one giant monitor, so there is no way to make your client be above only one of your server monitors. As for the configuration- you can either use the gui, or something like [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto)-

```
section: screens
        myserver:
        myclient:
end
section: links
        myserver:
                up = myclient
        myclient:
                down = myserver

end
```

(replace myserver and myclient with the names of your server and client, and save it as /etc/synergy.conf)